# 70's/80's sci-fi book about conscript trained to be a powerful warrior

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read a futuristic sci-fi book in the 1980's (maybe the 70's), about an overweight orphan who lived in slums, known as "the rat" (not the stainless steel rat), who was conscripted into space military service (in chapter 1). He was trained and became a powerful warrior and teamed up with others, and towards the end may have overthrown the governing beings.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/155070/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where? Also, take a look at our [tour](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Except for the part about a space military, you could be describing *Sugarat* of A. A. Attanasio's Nebula award nominated novel *Radix*, published in 1981.

In chapter one, you see *Sugarat* in action, a vigilante seeking vengeance in the night by killing the gang members terrorizing the city. When captured, *Sugarat* turns out to be Sumner Kagan, an overweight adolescent living with his mother. He is forced into the military, the Massebôth, who, among other responsibilities,  are tasked with keeping earth free of voors and distorts.

Sumner eventually escapes from the army, meets voors and distorts and others, eventually finding himself a weapon aimed at the heart of the future earth's power structure.

This is the first novel of the *Radix* tetrology; *Radix*, *In Other Worlds*, *Arc of the Dream*, and finally *The Last Legends of Earth*.

[image]

Comment: Holey mackerel! Exactly!!
I've been trying to recall this book for years.
Well done, Thank you!!!

Comment: The series is loosely connected. Books 2 & 3 are skippable, *Radix* and *The Last Legends of Earth* are among the best sf I've read.

Comment: @Dave, since you are new to the site, if this answer is correct, please mark it as such by clicking on the gray check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: I agree about Radix, my favorite (in my memory) after Asimov's Robots, Empire and Foundation. I will read the other two (just for completeness) in anticipation of LLoE. Any suggestions on how to obtain?

Comment: @Dave - [Try this.](https://www.amazon.com/Radix-Book-1-Attanasio/dp/0553254065/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1489848054&sr=8-1&keywords=A.+A.+Attanasio)