# Sci fi book where a rich kid is sent to prison and trained as a commando

Tags: story-identification, novel

In the early 90's I remember reading the start of a book but cannot recall the title.

The main character started out as a pudgy rich kid who got convicted for a crime after running with the wrong crowd, possibly as a rebellion against his parents.  Apparently he was genetically pure and instead of becoming a simple prisoner, he was instead ruthlessly trained into becoming some kind of commando.  I seem to recall him being forced to run around the prison walls all day.

I got transferred shortly after starting the book and never got a chance to finish it.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for asking good story-id questions to see if they help you remember any additional details you can [edit] into your question.  For example, do you remember what the cover looked like?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/155070/trying-to-find-a-sci-fi-book-from-the-70s-80s

Answer (score 6):

This is **"Radix" by A.A. Attanasio**, 1981. From [its wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_(novel)):

> Radix is the story of a young man's odyssey of self-discovery, from dangerous adolescent to warrior, from outcast to near-god, in a far-future Earth dramatically changed from the one we know.

The hero is described as you remember:

> Sumner Kagan: The novel's hero, an overweight rebellious young man from a dysfunctional single-parent family.

As [this review](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/a-a-attanasio/radix/) says, he

> is arrested, slimmed down by hard labor, trained as a Ranger...